# How do I specify deleting phrases in a .txt file with one phrase containing 'x' the other 'x' and 'y' (in which x to be deleted but x and y not)

Tags: python

So I got a .txt file in which there is a lot of data I got from my website and its visitors. In the code below I tried getting rid of some of the data by using a "`for line in lines: if  'x' not in line: file.write(line)` in which "line" is a variable.

The code itself works. I can delete a sentence containing `'"""Mozilla/5.0'` for example. This part of the sentence is in many of the data I got. Some of these same sentences contain also `"popsicle/nl"`. What do I need to do to delete the sentence with just `'"""Mozilla/5.0'` and keep the sentence with both `'"""Mozilla/5.0'` and `"popsicle/nl"`. Below here is my code: 
I hope I clarified my problem good enough! I am not that good in english :/

```
file = open(r'C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\python\School\DBsite.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines() 
file.close() 
file = open(r'C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\python\School\DBsite.txt', 'w')
for line in lines:
  if 'mijndomein.nl proxybot/0.1' not in line and 'mdh profiler/0.1' not in line and '"","Mozilla/5.0' not in line and 'Mozilla/5.1' not in line and 'index' not in line:
    file.write(line)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do everything on one line, spread it out and it might make more sense:

```py
for line in lines:
    if 'x' not in line or 'y' in line:
        file.write(line)
```

Comment: @kaya3, it is wrong, but your is too.  The op already has the `'x' not in line` part.  It really should be `'x' not in line or 'y' in line`. Editing now

Comment: Oh, good point, I didn't read carefully enough - your code writes a line (the opposite of deleting it), so the condition needs to be inverted.